# How can I JSON encode an array in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, vb.net, encode

I need to pass back a JSON result for a routine I am working with. In `VB.NET`, how can arrays be JSON encoded?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Dim serializer as New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim arrayJson as String = serializer.Serialize(myArray)
```

Comment: using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Answer (score 9):

There are four ways:

1. Roll your own with a Custom formatter
2. [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json).
3. [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)
4. [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

I recently blogged about how to do [Json Serialization](http://blog.framework-it.net/2009/02/json-serialization.html).

Comment: I've used Json.NET with much success, it's quite nice.

Comment: The code that bdukes post did the trick.  I will look into your 4 suggestions as well though.  Thanks!

Comment: bdukes is the one I actually recommend. It's item #3 in the list.

Comment: All are valid, with more or less hurdles, but I would go with option #2 (Json.NET)

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to look into JSON serialization.  [Here is a good article](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx) that explains one way to do it (unfortunately the examples are in C#) but with more information we can probalby steer you towards the right toolkit.

Comment: The link that you are referring to is dead.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the javascript serializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) I believe it was deprecated for a while by Microsoft but then un-deprecated (is that a word??) when they wanted to use it in MVC