# take vb.net server side arraylist and convert to javascript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an array list on my server side that i want to use on my client side as an array how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return it as [JavaScript Object Notation ( JSON )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) see this question here on StackOverflow on ["How can I encode an Array in VB.NET to JSON?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/579053/39106).

To quote @bdukes answer:

```
Dim serializer as New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim arrayJson as String = serializer.Serialize(myArray)
```