# JSON response opens as a file, but I can't access it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, response

In the code below I make a `POST` request to a servlet that replies in this way:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
json = "{success:true,sessionUid:\""+sessionUid+"\"}";
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

So Firefox opens it like a file and I can see it's ok. Here you have the JSON:

```
{success:true,sessionUid:"D07WC15R7LFRFRGPF4P5"}
```

The problem is that I can't inspect the JSON object. It seems not to exist inside my callback function (also using Firebug). Take a look to the code and alerts.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#loginForm").submit(function(response){
alert("response="+response);    //output: "response=[object Object]"
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
alert("obj.sessionUid="+obj.sessionUid);    //doesn't work, Firebug says "obj is null"
                    if (response.success == true){ //never true
                        document.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/QuoteroClient/logged.jsp';
                    }else{
                        alert("Something went wrong in the login process.");
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="loginForm" action="http://localhost:8080/QuoteroClient/Main?servlet=Security" method="post">
            <fieldset><legend>Login to Quotero:</legend>
                <label>Action:</label><input type="text" name="action" value="login"/><br />
                <label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="login-quotero" value="admin"/><br />
                <label>Password:</label><input type="text" name="password-quotero" value="admin" /><br />
                <label>Domain:</label><input type="text" name="combo-domain" value="Quotero" /><br />
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I also tried to do the same with an AJAX request, wothout success:

```
$("#ajaxSubmit").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET", //GET or POST is the same for this servlet
    url: "http://localhost:8080/QuoteroClient/Main?servlet=Security&action=login&login-quotero=admin&password-quotero=admin&combo-domain=Quotero",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
alert("response=" + response);
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON("" + response);
alert("obj.sessionUid=" + obj.sessionUid);
      if (response.success == true) {
        document.location.href = contextPath + 'http://localhost:8080/QuoteroClient/logged.jsp';
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong in the login process.");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: i dont understand if you use firebug why use the `alert()`? use `console.log(response);` that way you can see and even navigate a json object just like a file tree

Comment: I think ur problem could be on this line `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);` i think that response returns as jquery anyways dont need to parse it again.

Comment: are you trying to make this an ajax request? because otherwise submit is just an event handler not an ajax request.

Comment: @Val Thanks for the console.log(), something new for me! I tried to do it as an AJAX request, without success.. now I edit the question with that attempt.

Comment: remove `?servlet=Security&action=login&login-quotero=admin&password-quotero=admin&combo-domain=Quotero` and use the `data` option on my answer tells you how to `serialize` it, also check out `serializeArray`

Comment: btw if you are using php then u need to `json_encode();` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have mixed up ajax with submit. submit is just simply an event, when form is submitted do the following. then you can

```
 $("#loginForm").submit(function(){
     var post_data = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
        url: '',//url of the php file that handles the forms
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        data:post_data,//this are the query strings, e.g. ?q=blabla&s=blabla
        success:function (data){//if page was 200 or successfully loaded
             alert(data.sessionUid);
             // do what ever you wish with the data here
        },
        error: function (){
            alert('Page failed to load');
        }
     })
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: @Val thanks, you're being very useful. Anyway I did as you said but can't make it work. The result is the error alert

Comment: then you know that the url is not right. on `firebug` what number does it show ? on the `status` section on the `net` tab after you click submit, and a url should come up there with a status code

Comment: to be honest I have 0 experience with asp.net but this could also help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579053/how-can-i-encode-an-array-in-vb-net-to-json to encode a json from an array unless u are using php which is `json_encode($array)`

Comment: the URL is ok, status is 200 OK, but the net > reply tab is empty.. ASP or PHP? I'm using Java servlets.

Comment: ok the page is ok, the problem is that your page is returning plain text, and you need `json` I did a bit of google and found this http://objectmix.com/javascript/358117-how-send-json-data-result-java-servlet-javascript.html that might help although i have no clue about java either. but if anything google java servlets array to json or something like that

Comment: @bluish: Can you add the quotes around the keys and see if it helps? You would need to escape them with backslash, like this: `json = "{\"success\":true,\"sessionUid\":\""+sessionUid+"\"}";`

Comment: @rsp I can't, it's not my servlet

Comment: @bluish: OK, so we'll try a little workaround. Try adding this option to your jQuery ajax call: `dataFilter: function(data) { return data.replace('success','"success"').replace('sessionUid', '"sessionUid"'); },` (with the comma at the end) between `type: 'GET',` and `dataType:'json',` That way we'll see if it were the missing quotes that were causing the problem and at least we'll eliminate one possible cause if it doesn't help. Because as I said before I think that not having those quotes which may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @bluish if the success and sessionUid is the only two things that will return, then you would have to parse the data variable with jsonParse

Comment: @rsp he does not know what the sessionUid is. that wudnt work also no need to replace the sessionUid as it has the `"` already in it :) but he can replace the success with `"`

Comment: @Val: Please, I am seriously trying to help here. The sessionUid **value** has quotes, but the sessionUid **key** doesn't and I believe that this is causing the problem, as I am trying to explain from the very beginning. Adding the dataFilter exactly as I wrote it won't hurt and at least we'll see if the problem was the quotes or not. This is how you debug such things.

Comment: @bluish click submit, got to net tab on firebug then select response tab when u click the link it shows up, then copy and paste what that box shows?

Comment: @bluish: Are you getting something like: *Error: uncaught exception: Invalid JSON:* in your Firefox error console?

Comment: @Val @rsp I have nothing in Net > Response. While in Net > Headers > Response Headers I have `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4E449D8A1BF6D35825C7B3FE2921C710; Path=/QuoteroClient; HttpOnly
sessionUid=LFKVEVF9DR77ZJYODR4R
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 48
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 14:20:49 GMT"`
That `sessionUid` here sounds strange, doesn't it?.. where is `success`?

Comment: @rsp with a bit of work I could modify the servlet and make it return a quoted-keys json. In Net > Headers > Response Headers I noted 4 characters more in `Content-Length`, but the situation doesn't change.

Comment: ok well the problem is on your servlet then because its not returning anything. the header is used by the browser to deal with sessions and cookies, the response is the text you get or source code like html etc.

Comment: @bluish: Content-Length: 48 - this is the number of characters in the string with unquoted keys so it seems to be getting there but something is wrong after it gets to the browser. If I were you then I would try to add those double quotes if it is at all possible (remember about backslashes, see one of my comments above) just to see if it changes anything at all, maybe it gives a different error, maybe different message, so you may be a little bit closer to solving this mystery. Sorry but I have to go now. I wish you good luck.

Comment: @rsp I already tried your fix and Content-Length becomes 52 (4 quotes more). But no errors reported. Anyway thankyou very very much, to you and to @Val!! Now I'll forget about reading JSON and I'll search for another way for my case.

Comment: try to use xml, or simply, html tags :) if you could that can be done as good as json its just a few characters more on your bandwidth :)

Comment: I haven't solved my problem but I accept this, because probably my problem comes from a different cause. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid JSON:

```
{success:true,sessionUid:"D07WC15R7LFRFRGPF4P5"}
```

This is valid JSON:

```
{"success":true,"sessionUid":"D07WC15R7LFRFRGPF4P5"}
```

In JSON the keys must always be quoted. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DfgHu/).

Comment: it is not necessary to escape keys with quotes, unless they collide with predefined values like CLASS, FOR, etc.

Comment: thats not strictly true, the quotes are optional, however they do help when certain name clash with native javascript keywords e.g. `delete` etc...

Comment: @Nazariy: It is always necessary to quote keys in JSON. See [the spec](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: oops sorry @nazariy you was quicker :)

Comment: @Val: The quotes are mandatory. Always. See [the spec](http://www.json.org/) if you don't believe me.

Comment: @rsp you are just confirming what we have just mentioned :) neither success, or sessionUid conflic with js so its just pointless and yes json recommends using them

Comment: @rsp thanks everybody. but what can I do if I can't modify the JSON the servlet sends me? "success" and "sessionUid" are not keywords, so it's not a problem?

Comment: @Val: If you don't believe me and the actual spec, then see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YSVQy/

Comment: @bluish: It is a problem because in JSON every key must be quoted. See the demo in the comment above.

Comment: thats because you are parsing it on quotes from a string so it has to be that way. http://jsfiddle.net/YSVQy/1/ there you are so u can better understand it.

Comment: @Val: I am parsing it exactly like jQuery does. Seriously, see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/DfgHu/ that actually uses jQuery to parse it. It's even explained on the jQuery.parseJSON documentation if you don't want to read the spec at json.org.

Comment: are you serious? I said it earlier you need to put quotes if u need to parse it from a string aka plain text. and I have read the damn specs get off my back. its like in php just because they recommend `array('key'=>'value');` does not mean that you cannot do `array('k e y'=>'value')` ... if the page returned was a valid ajax why would you have to parse it again? that means `header('content: application/json')` as well as `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: @Val: Of course I am serious. jQuery.ajax internally uses jQuery.parseJSON and parseJSON needs well formed JSON with mandatory quotes around every key. See the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ because it explains it quite well.

Comment: ok read English now. HE DOES NOT NEED to use `$.parseJson` because the file itself its a `json` file just like xml, html, css, js.

Comment: @Val: I don't know what he needs, all I'm saying is what he **does**. By calling $.ajax() he implicitly calls $.parseJSON(). This is how jQuery actually works. You may not like it but $.ajax calls $.parseJSON and $.parseJSON doesn't handle invalid JSON input with unquoted keys. I'm sorry but this is how it works and this is most likely the problem here. Try putting valid JSON there, preferably using json_encode() in PHP that would put the quotes where they belong and it might solve the problem.