# Get JavaScript JSON code in IE using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I have a string in a div element like this:

```
['39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78', '39.55,115.78']
```

I want get this list object using jQuery in Internet Explorer. What can I do?

Comment: r u getting same value again and again? `'39.55,115.78'`

Comment: Do you want to access its elements as just strings like '39.55,115.78' or the individual numbers like 39.55 and 115.78?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.parseJSON($("#yourDiv").text())
```

However, JSON requires that you use double-quotes, whereas you are using single-quotes in your example. If you want to parse it anyway, you could replace them in your string:

```
$.parseJSON($("#yourDiv").text().replace(/'/g, "\""))
```

Comment: AFAIK  `parseJSON` works with json string...is it json string written in question??

Comment: No, because it uses single-quotes instead of double-quotes. However, since the question is tagged "json" and includes "json" in the title I decided that this was probably the answer he would prefer. :)

Comment: Isn't your replace backwards?

Answer (score 2):

Read this...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

It looks like you string is not a well formed jSON string.

EDIT:
and this... 
http://www.json.org/example.html

Comment: +1 for knowing the JSON syntax - a rare thing these days - see comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180762/json-response-opens-as-a-file-but-i-cant-access-it-with-javascript/5180819#5180819). ;)