# How to create JSON array using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, json

How to create this `JSON` array using `vb.net` array

```
var data = {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};
```

Comment: Been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579053/how-can-i-encode-an-array-in-vb-net-to-json

Answer (score 8):

As you're using .NET 2.0 you have to use the JSON libary by James, with download at Codeplex (version for .NET 2.0).

An example of using Json.NET

Add a reference to **Newtonsoft.Json**, and an **Import Newtonsoft.Json** in your class.

Example:

```
Import Newtonsoft.Json

Dim product As New Product()
product.Name = "Captopril"
product.Expiry = New DateTime(2008, 12, 28)
product.Price = 3.99D
product.Sizes = New String() {"Small", "Medium", "Large"}


'Call SeralizeObject to convert the object to JSON string'
Dim output As String = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(product)
```

The output variable will hold the value:

```
{
  "Name": "Captopril",
  "Expiry": "\/Date(1230375600000+1300)\/",
  "Price": 3.99,
  "Sizes": [
    "Small",
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It says that both Product() and JavaScriptConvert are  not defined.

Comment: Yes, I used the NuGet console to install the necessary dependencies

Answer (score 6):

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property value As String
    Public Property name As Integer
End Class
```

On Page_Load:

```
'creating sample student ojects
    Dim obj1 As New Student() With {.value = "Mick Jagger", .name = 21}
    Dim obj2 As New Student() With {.value = "Johnny Storm", .name = 43}
    Dim obj3 As New Student() With {.value = "Richard Hatch", .name = 46}
    Dim obj4 As New Student() With {.value = "Kelly Slater", .name = 54}
    'adding student objects to list
    Dim objStudentList As New List(Of Student)() From { obj1,obj2, obj3, obj4}

    Dim objJSSerializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()

    'Serialization .NET Object to JSON
    strJSON = objJSSerializer.Serialize(objStudentList)

    Dim csname2 As String = "ButtonClickScript"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Dim cstext2 As New StringBuilder()
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    cstext2.Append("<script type=""text/javascript""> var data = {items: " + strJSON)
    cstext2.Append(" }; </")
    cstext2.Append("script>")
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname2, cstext2.ToString(), False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the visual studio gallery extension called JSON.net or go to their codeplex page ([JSON on codeplex](http://json.codeplex.com))