# Desktop server and client android

Tags: android, vb.net, client

i want to make a client application in android , to connect with my application which will be the server in vb.net , over internet , with mobile connected with 3g or WiFi to pass values to my server in vb.net. how to do this i don't have any idea about this topic please help and suggest any website relevant to this . 
regards

Comment: desktop server not a good idea

Comment: will not a server, but to send picture to android app and get msg from android

Answer (score 0):

if you can make JSON array you can receive date in Android app 
see this for make JSON :

[CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563748/how-to-create-json-array-using-vb-net)

and for filter your date can send with Http method from android app to VB see this :

[CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net)