# Sending an Array of Strings over the Network

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, tcpclient

I'm trying to retrieve usernames in a listview which is in string format. What I want to do is retrieve those usernames and store them in an array of strings and send them over the network, so that the receiving part can extract them and place those usernames in a listview.

But the problem is, I'm having a bad time sending an array of strings over the network. I know how to send a string over the network but I don't know how to send and array of strings over the network.

What I'm thinking is, maybe I should use a loop to store and extract the strings? But I don't know exactly how to do it.

**Here's my code for sending.**

```
'Say, this array contains the following strings
Dim strData() As String = {"Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"}

If networkStream.CanWrite Then

       'This is not the proper way. What should I do here?
       Dim SentData As Byte()

       SentData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData)

       NetworkStream.Write(SentData, 0, SentData.Length())

End If
```

**And here's my code for receiving.**

```
Dim rcvData() As String

If networkStream.CanWrite Then

       'Again, I don't think this is the proper way of handling an array of strings.
       Dim ByteData(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte

       NetworkStream.Read(ByteData, 0, CInt(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))

       rcvData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteData)

End If
```

Comment: ASCII.GetBytes doesn't have an overload that accepts a string array. Your code doesn't compile

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: It's important that you don't simply ignore the result of `NetworkStream.Read` as you are not guaranteed to receive the whole messages in a single go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII.GetBytes doesn't have an overload that accepts a string array. 
Before converting data you need to Join your string array, then send a single string.

```
Dim strData() As String = {"Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"}

If networkStream.CanWrite Then

   Dim toSend = String.Join(";", strData)
   Dim SentData As Byte()
   SentData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend)
   NetworkStream.Write(SentData, 0, SentData.Length())
End If
```

of course, on the receiving end you should dejoin the string received

```
 Dim rcvData As String

 If networkStream.CanRead Then
     Dim bytesReceived As Integer = 0
     Dim ByteData(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
     Do
         bytesReceived = networkStream.Read(ByteData, 0, CInt(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
         rcvData = rcvData + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteData, 0, bytesReceived)
     Loop While networkStream.DataAvailable
     Dim strData = rcvData.Split(";")
 End If
```

Comment: You are ignoring the result of `NetworkStream.Read` and assuming you are reading the whole message in one go.

Comment: Wow! That is purely genius! Thanks for that. I should try this. :D

Comment: @DanielKelley of course you are right, in a real world app you need to be fail safe and check on size received.

Comment: Just be careful that none of your strings in your array contain the `;` character (or whatever character you use as the delimiter.  Using a delimiter is certainly the simplest and most efficient method, but if data size is not a major issue, I'd recommend using XML or JSON instead.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I'm 100% sure it won't. As I've said it will contain usernames. And those usernames will actually be first names. So, I don't really think that those usernames would contain `;`. LOL. Anyways, thanks for pointing that out. I'll keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

You know how to send a single string, but not an array of them? So encode the array in a string, and send *that*. Try [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) (see [How can I JSON encode an array in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579053/how-can-i-encode-an-array-in-vb-net-to-json)) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Comment: Encode the array in a string? This sounds foreign to me but I'll try to look on that.