# Onclick event not running in tr. Table generated in vb.net through a literal

Tags: javascript, vb.net, onclick, literals, tr

Hello I have an onclick event in a  that isn't working. Can someone take a look to see what I'm missing? I generate the html from vb.net using a literal. Other instances of the onclick even work in other similar `<tr>`'s but this one won't work. There are many tables generated this way but some of them just don't function. The onclick isn't even happening.

```
<table class="redtbl"><tr><td>050-CONFIGURATION     
MANAGEMENT</td></tr><tr id="050-CONFIGURATION     
MANAGEMENTRT06420-11" style="display:none;"><td>Planned Effort: 1</td></tr><tr id="050-    CONFIGURATION     
MANAGEMENTRT06420-12" style="display:none;"><td>Actual Effort: </td></tr><tr id="050-    CONFIGURATION     
MANAGEMENTRT06420-13" style="display:none;"><td>Assignee: </td></tr><tr class ="redtr"><td onclick="run('050-CONFIGURATION     
MANAGEMENTRT06420-1')">Assigned</td></tr></table>
```

This is the html code when I click on view source. It's layout seems pretty messed up. I'm wondering if it is from all of the spaces that get somehow added. Here is a nice view of what it should look like in a perfect world.

```
<table class="redtbl">
  <tr>
    <td>050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-11" style="display:none;">
    <td>Planned Effort: 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-12" style="display:none;">
    <td>Actual Effort: </td>
  </tr><tr id="050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-13"style="display:none;">
    <td>Assignee: </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class ="redtr">
    <td onclick="run('050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-1')">Assigned</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I write the code in vb.net I do it in this format

```
Literal3.Text = "<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>"
```

here is where it is actually generated in the vb code

```
Literal3.Text &= "<tr>" &
                            "<td>" &
                                "<table" & colortbl & ">" &
                                    "<tr>" &
                                        "<td>" & MyDataReader(5) & "</td>" &
                                    "</tr>" &
                                    "<tr id=""" & MyDataReader(5).ToString & MyDataReader(2).ToString & "1" & """ style=""display:none;"">" &
                                        "<td>Planned Effort: " & MyDataReader(6) & "</td>" &
                                    "</tr>" &
                                    "<tr id=""" & MyDataReader(5).ToString & MyDataReader(2).ToString & "2" & """ style=""display:none;"">" &
                                        "<td>Actual Effort: " & MyDataReader(7) & "</td>" &
                                    "</tr>" &
                                    "<tr id=""" & MyDataReader(5).ToString & MyDataReader(2).ToString & "3" & """ style=""display:none;"">" &
                                        "<td>Assignee: " & MyDataReader(8) & "</td>" &
                                    "</tr>" &
                                    "<tr" & colortr & ">" &
                                        "<td onclick=""run('" & MyDataReader(5).ToString & MyDataReader(2).ToString & "')"">" & MyDataReader(4) & "</td>" &
                                    "</tr>" &
                                "</table>" &
                            "</td>" &
                        "</tr>"
```

sorry if this post is long, I just want to be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linebreak in your string you are passing to your `run` function, this will give you a syntax error.
Try to remove the newline characters from the data or encode it properly.

Comment: I don't understand where the linebreak is coming from. I did remove the newline characters and have the string all in one line and I still get the problem. What would be the proper way to encode?

Comment: @TitanicSwimmer look up JSON serialization - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579053/how-can-i-encode-an-array-in-vb-net-to-json

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the function run , that function must be in the header of your document

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function run (arg) {
        window.alert(arg);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="redtbl">
        <tr>
            <td>050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-11" style="display:none;">
            <td>Planned Effort: 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-12" style="display:none;">
            <td>Actual Effort: </td>
        </tr><tr id="050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-13"style="display:none;">
            <td>Assignee: </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class ="redtr">
            <td onclick="run('050-CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENTRT06420-1')">Assigned</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gusatvo_beavis/FbJRL/

Comment: I advise you not to use script inline and style in line

Comment: I was just showing a portion of the code, the function run() is there.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was the data that I was pulling from the datareader, there were some funky characters, that were causing the linebreaks. So I'm basing my id's on something else.