# Passing data from codebehind to javascript for use in Google Timeline

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to use a Google [timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#Overview) with some user-defined data from my codebehind file. I keep getting an error, "Row given with size different than 4 (the number of columns in the table)."

In my code, the page loads and the user data is retrieved from the db. The page's javascript accesses the data from the megastring string variable as shown below. I added "=" in the codebehind at the end of what will become the google timeline row so I can split the string into rows for the javascript array tablerows. However when I do that, I get an extra blank row in tablerows, hence the tablelength variable being used in the for loop.

If I don't convert the string from the codebehind into a javascript array I get the following error "Every row given must be either null or an array."

The for loop goes through and replaces the placeholder for apostrophe with actual apostrophes for the google timeline. The final formatted data is saved in the javascript array finalrows.

Right now, I am just trying to pass "[ 'President', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)]=" from the codebehind. When I output the finalrow variable to an alert, it looks like [ 'President', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)]. I'm not sure why I keep getting an error about the rows.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var rawstring = '<%= megaString%>';
    var tablerows = rawstring.split("=");
    var finalrows = new Array();
    var tablelength = tablerows.length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < tablelength; i++) {
        var tempstr = tablerows[i];
        tempstr = tempstr.replace(/&apos;/g, "'");
        finalrows[i] = tempstr;
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        finalrows
    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

Comment: Are you serializing the Megastring properly in the code-behind file ?

Comment: Your rows are still strings, not arrays.  It should be possible to fix this in your codebehind (using `'` instead of `&apos;` and using `,` instead of `=`), and then you can just output `megaString` without having to do any conversion: `dataTable.addRows([<%= megaString %>]);`.

Comment: @Ani, I am not serializing megastring. Do I have to do that in order to use it in the code above?

Comment: @asgallant, your suggestion worked. Thanks a million. I originally tried passing megastring into a javascript variable and using that in the dataTable.addRows(). Never tried just using megastring directly. Thanks!

Comment: @Ani, serialization is suggested in some other posts about passing arrays from codebehind to javascript. I've never used it before though. What is the advantage over asgallant's suggestion? Would be interested to know.

Comment: Ideally, your server-side scripting would support a method of serializing arrays or hashmaps (or whatever the appropriate data structure is in the language you use) to JSON strings, which javascript can natively convert to objects and arrays.  It looks like you are working with VB in ASP.net, which would mean you should have access to the `JavaScriptSerializer` class (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/579062/613559) for example code).